Проблема с гугл скриптом. Проверка на странице наличия ссылок
помогите, пожалуйста. Мне нужен код, который будет брать ссылку со столбца А, начиная с А2, проверять наличие ссылок в тексте страницы в блоке short description и и основного текста на главную и другие страницы сайта. Если естьссылка в статье наглавную, то ставить галочку в стоблце Q напротив ссылки и если есть ссылка на другую страницу, но не главная, то ставить галочку в столбце R. Код почему-то работает некоректно.
function checkLinks() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var urls = range.getValues();
  var resultsQ = [];
  var resultsR = [];

  urls.forEach(function(row) {
    var url = row[0];
    var response;
    try {
      response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
      if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
        var content = response.getContentText();

        // Точные регулярные выражения для проверки наличия анкорных ссылок
        var descHasLinks = /class="header-banner--desc".*?<a\s[^>]*href="https?:\/\/1xbetmy.com\/(?!go\/)[^"]*"[^>]*>(?!\s*<\/a>).*?<\/a>/is.test(content);
        var contentHasLinks = /class="wp-block-group__inner-container is-layout-constrained wp-block-group-is-layout-constrained".*?<a\s[^>]*href="https?:\/\/1xbetmy.com\/(?!go\/)[^"]*"[^>]*>(?!\s*<\/a>).*?<\/a>/is.test(content);

        resultsQ.push([descHasLinks ? '✓' : '']);
        resultsR.push([contentHasLinks ? '✓' : '']);
      } else {
        resultsQ.push(['']);
        resultsR.push(['']);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error fetching URL:', url, 'Error:', e.toString());
      resultsQ.push(['']);
      resultsR.push(['']);
    }
  });

  // Обновление данных в таблице
  sheet.getRange("Q2:Q" + (urls.length + 1)).setValues(resultsQ);
  sheet.getRange("R2:R" + (urls.length + 1)).setValues(resultsR);
}


"Код почему-то работает некоректно." - что именно некорректно?

@АлексейР Он ставит галочки везде. Где нужно и не нужно. Честно, даже не знаю в чем проблема, в какйо части кода

Отладку пробовали?

@АлексейР Честно говоря, я не особо программист, я СЕО) Я хотел напечатать с помощью гпт, но не вышло.
